# Can you access variable attributes in the django template language with other variables?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Let's say I have two variables - User and Fruitlist. User is a model instance, while fruitlist is a list.

```
{% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user.title }} </td>
                <td>{{ user.text }} </td>
                {% for fruit in fruitlist %}
                        <td>{{ user.fruit }} </td>
                {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to create a table with the code above where a column is created for each fruit in fruitlist, and that column is filled with the value of an attribute user.fruit (the user model has a field for every fruit which contains a value).

Why doesn't the above code work?

EDIT:

Solution for original question bellow - following is regarding forms

For forms:

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
                {% if user|get_attr:fruit != True %}
                    {{ form|get_attr:fruit }}
                {% else %}
                    <p>&#10003; {{ fruit }}</p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is user.fruit? Is it a string or a foreign key?

Comment: An integer field. So if the first fruit in the list fruits is “banana”, it should return the value of user.banana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because the attribute fruit is interpreted as a string.

You can write a custom filter to retrieve attributes as variables in your templates.

```
# your_app_name/templatetags/your_app_name_tags.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_attr(obj, attr):
    return getattr(obj, attr)
```

Then in your template

```
{% load your_app_name_tags %}

{% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user.title }} </td>
                <td>{{ user.text }} </td>
                {% for fruit in fruitlist %}
                        <td>{{ user|get_attr:fruit }} </td>
                {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works for loading model object attribtues - but when I try using this for a modelform , I get the error message "object has no attribute" even though it does. Do I need a custom filter for forms?

Comment: @LarsLill, to get model attributes you need to access a model instance. Use form.instance syntax to access the model instance of a modelform. E.g. form.instance.user

Comment: to clarify - I want the form widget rendered. Maybe I made a mistake, but adding .instance just gives me the value.

Comment: @LarsLill, I think we need to see your template with the form to get what you want to achieve. You can render form fields with form.field and access model data with form.instance.attribute.

Comment: Ok, added it now. The code gives me an attributeerror which tells me the form I'm using has no such attribute as the one being called(ie. "banana") - but the form does have that field and calling it works if I do it manually.

Comment: @LarsLill, please share your code. Otherwise it's not possible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Added it in the main post, but here we go: 

{% for fruit in fruits %}
                {% if user|get_attr:fruit != True %}
                    {{ form|get_attr:fruit }}
                {% else %}
                    <p>&#10003; {{ fruit }}</p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<td>{{ user.fruit }} </td>
```

With:

```
<td>{{ user[fruit] }} </td>
```

Luckily you can access an attribute like it was a dictionary key here.

Although, from what you have described, this might not be the correct solution.

If the list of fruits is like:

```
fruitlist = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Then it should be an applicable solution

Comment: List does indeed appear like that - but unfortunately I'm getting a parse-error when I try this.